# Unable to access SQL Server database due to in sufficient space

Tags: sql-server

I am having a huge database on one of my drives, Now the size of the database is increased, Even now its completely full, I got the back up of the database and then i tried to delete the records to free the space, As i was deleting records i got error regarding transaction log is full, I am having only mdf and ldf file in this drive, that is why i am unable to free more space and now i can not even perform simple queries due to the space issue. What should i do now, Where from i can clear the ldf file? and how can make my db to run smoothly again.

Comment: try adding more space,since delete is logged,it will try to use space

Comment: As mentioned having only these two files, I have to play around with only these two files.

Comment: why not add space ,if it is production db

Answer (score 0):

if I remember well... in query analyzer or equivalent:

```
BACKUP LOG  databasename  WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

DBCC SHRINKFILE (  databasename_Log, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a production database:

Set the recovery model to simple.

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

For all databases you can shrink them:

```
USE [Databasename]
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'Databasename' ) --shrink the database
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Databasename' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY) --shrink the mdf file
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Databasename_Log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY) --shrink the ldf file
```

Also make sure the database autogrowth is not set in % .
Right click on the database in SSMS => Properties => Files => Autogrowth